# why vim expand doesn't work

Tags: vim, ctags

I type `:echo expand("<cword>")`, vim shall show the word on the cursor.
But when I type `:tag expand("<cword>")`, it prompts:

> E426: tag not found: expand(

It seems that, the expand function is not called on the tag function, `expand(` is sent to `tag` as a parameter.

Thanks in advance for any insights.
Any reference is prefered.

Comment: `:echo`, `:let` and maybe other commands i forget are designed to accept vim expressions, with vars, funcs... But most of other commands do not. Please imagine: would you really like to always type `:e "myfile.txt"`, with quotes? It would be really unproductive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vimscript is evaluated exactly like the Ex commands typed in the `:` command-line. There were no variables in `ex`, so there's no way to specify them. When typing a command interactively, you'd probably use `<C-R>=` to insert variable contents:

```
:tag <C-R>=expand('<cword>')<CR><CR>
```

... (well, actually there's the shorter `<C-R><C-W>` for the current word).

In a script, `:execute` must be used. All the literal parts of the Ex command must be quoted (single or double quotes), and then concatenated with the variables:

```
:execute 'tag' expand('<cword>')
```

Comment: hi, Ingo, what is the difference between <C-R> and <CR>? And what does he  trailing <CR><CR> do?

Comment: `<C-R>` is Control plus R. In command-line mode, this inserts the contents of a register; here, the special `=` expression register is used. `<CR>` is the Enter key; we need it twice: Once to conclude the expression entry, once more to finish the command-line.